# Find the highest ranked item of a list from another list

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a list of items already ordered by highest rank that I store in variable **topList**.

Then I have current list of items that I store in variable **currentList**

The goal is to find the element of currentList who is the highest ranked in topList.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MethodName14() {
    var topList = new List<string>() {"AB", "DC", "ZG"}; // ordered by highest rank
    var currentList = new List<string> {"ZG", "DC"};
    var actual = ReturnTop(currentList, topList);
    Assert.Equal("DC", actual); // because DC is in index 2 and ZG is in index 3
}

private string ReturnTop(List<string> currentList, List<string> topList) {
    string result = null;
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var current in currentList) {
        var lookupedCurrentIndex = topList.FindIndex(a => a == current);
        if (index == 0) {
            result = topList[index];
            index = lookupedCurrentIndex;
        } else {
            if (lookupedCurrentIndex < index) {
                index = lookupedCurrentIndex;
                result = topList[index];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

My method ReturnTop is too slow, it's O(n²). Can we do better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation is O(N*T), where N is the number of items in your query list, and T is the number of items in the top list; it is O(1) in use of space.

If you do not mind increasing the use of space to O(N), you can implement an algorithm in O(N+T) by constructing a hash set from query words, and searching for the first word in `topList` that matches one of query words, as follows:

```
var knownWords = new HashSet<string>(currentList);
return topList.FirstOrDefault(w => knownWords.Contains(w));
```

Constructing `knownWords` takes O(N) time and O(N) space. Searching `topList` for the earliest item that exists in `knownWords` takes O(T) time and O(1) space, because hash set look-up is O(1).

This can be further shortened to this (thank you, [Slai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383168/slai)!)

```
return topList.Intersect(currentList).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: seems like it can be shortened to `topList.Intersect(currentList).FirstOrDefault()` https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ae06318d1f5fb355

Answer (score 0):

```
var topList = new List<string>() {"AB", "DC", "ZG"}; // ordered by highest rank
var currentList = new List<string> {"ZG", "DC"};

var bestItem = currentList.OrderBy(item => topList.FindIndex(a => a == item)).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(bestItem);
```

http://csharppad.com/gist/b6f3b41afb86018c6f81284cc4ae22b5

Comment: Although this implementation is much shorter than that of OP, 'OrderBy' uses linear search for item comparison, so this algorithm is O(T*N*Log N), i.e. slightly worse asymptotically than OP's O(T*N) algorithm.

Comment: I suspected something's fishy ;)

Answer (score 0):

With solution below searching of top item will take O(N + M)(where N is amount of topList items and M is amount of current list) which can be count as O(2N)

It will loop once all items of `topList` while creating a dictionary.
And will loop once all items of `current` for searching item with min index.

```
private string ReturnTop(IEnumerable<string> current, IEnumerable<string> topList)
    {
        var topMap = topList.Select((value, index) => new {Value = value, Index = index})
                            .ToDictionary(item => item.Value, item => item.Index);

        string minItem = null;
        int minPosition = topMap.Count;
        foreach (var item in current)
        {
            var currentPosition = topMap[item];
            if (currentPosition == 0)
            {
                return item;
            }

            if (currentPosition < minPosition)
            {
                minPosition = currentPosition;
                minItem = item;
            }
        }

        return minItem;
    }
```